# Retrieving key attribute names of a given table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, primary-key

I am working on a database middleware application again. I want to retrieve the names of all key values of a given table.

For instance:

CREATE TABLE foo(A INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, B VARCHAR(255))

I want to ask Oracle for the primary keys of 'foo' and I want to get 'A'.

Is this possible in Oracle at all? I tried to search their documentation but wasn't able to find anything of value.

Thanks in advance

Kage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source:](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/find_pkeys.php)

```
SELECT       cols.table_name
             , cols.column_name
             , cols.position
             , cons.status
             , cons.owner
FROM         all_constraints cons
             , all_cons_columns cols
WHERE        cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND          cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND          cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND          cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY     cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

> Make sure to type the table_name in
>   uppercase, as **Oracle stores all table
>   names in uppercase.** Let's quickly
>   explain the output from this query.
>   table_name is the name of the table
>   (stored in uppercase). **column_name is
>   the name of the column that is a part
>   of the primary key.** (also stored in
>   uppercase) position is the position in
>   the primary key. A primary key can
>   contain more than one column, so
>   understanding the order of the columns
>   in the primary key is very important.
>   status indicates whether the primary
>   key is currently enabled or disabled.
>   owner indicates the schema that owns
>   the table.

[ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm) - here is a very good description of ALL_CONSTRAINTS

[ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1035.htm) - here is a very good description of ALL_CONS_COLUMNS

Comment: Wow, thanks. I think this is will help. Thanks Svetlozar :-). What would have been appropriate search terms for this on the Oracle documentation page? Constraints?

Comment: Small comment - **Oracle does not store all of its table names in upper case**. It defaults all object names to upper case on creation, however if you wrap an object name in quotes [e.g. `create table "lower" (col_id number);`] then Oracle will keep the defined case [i.e. `select * from lower` will fail for the table created above, but `select * from "lower"` will succeed]. I've come across this for some auto-generation scripts when I couldn't work out why I couldn't see a table. You can also have some fun by adding spaces to the start and end of table names to mess with the DBAs minds!

Comment: Evil >:). I've run across the uppercase "problem" before, but adding spaces is one layer up. Hrr. Thanks, Chris ^^